# SSDT Error on Publish but not on Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, sql-server-data-tools

I have been using SSDT with VS2013 and up to now have found that when a stored procedure references a column that does not exist the build fails.

Today I have successfully built a project but found the publish failed. The error was the standard "Permission has an unresolved reference to object [table].[column]". I know this was due to a stored procedure looking for a column that no longer existed.

My question is why the build was successful in the first place, as surely this is where the failure should have occurred. Is there a config option that controls this behaviour at build level?

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios here that behave differently.

**Scenario 1:** A stored procedure that references a non-existing column in a table that is defined in the database project will produce an error and prevent the build from succeeding.

**Scenario 2:** A stored procedure that references a table that is not defined in the database project will produce a warning and will not prevent the build from succeeding.

Scenario 2 is the more interesting one, because when you try to publish the project it's possible for the publish to succeed or fail, depending on what's in the target database and how you've configured the deployment settings.  For example, suppose that:

- Your stored procedure contains a reference to dbo.SomeTable.Column1
- Your database project doesn't contain a definition for dbo.SomeTable

In this case, if the target database doesn't contain dbo.SomeTable, deployment will succeed, because SQL Server allows procedures to reference non-existing tables (a feature known as delayed-name resolution).

But suppose that the target database does contain dbo.SomeTable. If dbo.SomeTable on the target database actually has a column named Column1, the deployment will succeed.  But if dbo.SomeTable on the target database doesn't have a column named Column1, the deployment will fail.

It's not clear which scenario you've encountered.  If it's more like Scenario 1, where you have an invalid reference to a table that is defined in the database project, but for some reason SSDT doesn't produce an error, then that's a bug and it would be good to log a Connect issue for this at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx using the category "Developer Tools (SSDT, BIDS, etc.)".

Comment: If you want scenario 2 to fail the build you can enable "Treat Transact-SQL warnings as errors" and it will fail the build (I like to have this enabled anyway as a good practice) as although you could deploy the code won't run (until the table was created)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback this is a really thorough insight that I know will prove useful. I intend to look at this again today but in the meantime:

Treat Transact-SQL warnings as errors did cause warnings as errors but not this error.This issue was not actually recorded under warnings. It was however showing as a warning in the output tab. 

In this instance the publish was a clean one so the Target DB did not exist prior to the publish. I believe, but will re-check, that the Table is defined. This would push me back to scenario 1 but as I say I will re-check this.